# Let $E$ be a Banach space, if $\alpha: E\to E$ and $\beta:E^*\to E^*$ are linear maps s.t for all $x \in E,y\in E^*$ $y(\alpha(x))=\beta(y(x))$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a Banach space, if $\alpha: E\to E$ and $\beta:E^*\to E^*$ are linear maps s.t for all $x \in E,y\in E^*$ $y(\alpha(x))=\beta(y)(x)$ Show $\alpha,\beta$ are bounded.

I am pretty sure I can prove that if $\alpha$ is bounded $\iff$ $\beta$ is bounded. $\beta$ sends $y(x) \to y(\alpha)(x)$ so its norm is at most $\|\alpha\|$. Now if $\beta$ is bounded, then $f(\alpha)$ is a bounded linear functional for all $f$. Hence consider the set $\{\alpha(x)| \|x\|\leq 1\}$ this can be identified with a  set in $E^{**}$ and by UBP we know it is uniformly bounded, thus $\alpha$ is bounded. However, I am not sure what to do now.

Comment: Have you tried the closed graph Theorem?

Comment: @Ruy I tried using closed graph theorem simultaneously on alpha and beta, to no avail.

Comment: I guess you now have an answer based on closed graph Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

If $x_n \to x$ and $\alpha(x_n) \to y$ then for all $f \in E^*$ we have that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ so that $\big[\beta(f)\big](x_n) \to \big[\beta(f)\big](x)$ i.e., $f(\alpha(x_n)) \to f(\alpha(x))$.

But we also know that $f(\alpha(x_n)) \to f(y)$ since $\alpha(x_n) \to y$. Thus $f(\alpha(x)) = f(y)$ for all $f \in E^*$.

$E^*$ separates points in $E$, and since $f \in E^*$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $y=\alpha(x)$.

Thus $\alpha$ is bounded by the closed graph theorem. Then $\beta$ is also bounded, being the canonical adjoint of $\alpha$.